# Program stuck at Vector of Class definition

Tags: c++

I defined a class and then created a vector of class and initialize the row and column:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Vertex {
    // class definition
};

int main()
{
    std::vector <std::vector <Vertex> > v1(2,std::vector <Vertex>(2));
    std::cout << "end of the program";
}
```

I'm using Eclipse and when I run the program there is no error but in the console window I cannot see the "end of the program" output. It seems the program stuck at vector definition.

Comment: `void main` should be `int main`.

Comment: You missed al `;` semicolon after the class declaration's closing `}` brace.

Comment: You also didn't include <vector> or qualify the name with `std::`.

Comment: I gave your code some std's. Cheers.

Comment: This is probably an Eclipse problem. I have had console logging not appear on vanilla installations of Eclipse CDT. There is a fix somewhere -- just google your problem and dig it up. It's a known issue.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. The code does not have an error, but still I have a the problem as the program stops in the middle. Not only cout, but also other commands after vector definition will not be run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush `cout`'s buffers:

```
std::cout << "end of the program" << std::flush;
```

Comment: This happens when `std::cout` is destroyed.

Comment: @chris And when exactly would that be if the prog is started from within Eclipse? Maybe only when the console window closes. That would be the case with the usual VS tricks (wait for a key press). I'm not sure.

Comment: @PeterSchneider, I would think it's a lot easier to have a console window that runs the program, followed by a `pause` command than to inject pausing code.

Comment: Thank you,
But your suggestion does not work. The problem is related to the vector definition, not cout<<. Because the rest of the commands after vector definition would not be run.